# How do you create a popup html populated with data generated from a separate Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, firefox-addon-webextensions

All the tutorials I've found on popups are just slightly different than what I need and I don't have the know-how to modify them to my needs.

I have a browser_action icon set which creates a popup from an HTML when you click on it, and I have a javascript in a separate file that sends an XMLHttpRequest to an API.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm open to other ways of accomplishing a similar result if this is not feasible:

I want popup.html to appear when the browser add-on button is pressed; then popup.html should run the script httpsdetect.js, which will receive data from another site; and finally, httpsdetect.js should display the data it received back into popup.html.

Here is what I have so far.

A manifest.json:

```html
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "HTTPS Detect",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Whatever",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
},

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icons/browser-32.png",
  "default_title": "Page Info",
  "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
}

}
```

Popup.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>

<script src="httpsdetect.js"></script> 
    
    
  </body>

</html>
```

A CSS file:

```html
html, body {
  width: 100px;
}

.responseText {
  margin: 3% auto;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: #E5F2F2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.responseText:hover {
  background-color: #CFF2F2;
}
```

A JavaScript that sends a GET request to another API. Currently, it's just sending the received data to the console, but I want it to populate the popup.html instead:

```html
console.log("Site hostname is: " + window.location.hostname);
var requestURL = "http://www.freegeoip.net/xml/" + window.location.hostname;
getRequest(requestURL, theCallback);

function getRequest(requestURL, theCallback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", requestURL, true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      theCallback(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);
}

function theCallback(theResponse) {
  console.log(theResponse);
}
```

Comment: Please include all of your *manifest.json*.  Currently, there is no indication how your JavaScript is being run.  Normally, in addition of any background script, you would have at least one `<script>` tag in your *popup.html* which specified the file from which to get the JavaScript for the popup.

Comment: popup.html appears when the add-on button is pressed, but the script, httpsdetect.js, is not executed.

Comment: Is the JavaScript in the question *httpsdetect.js*? If it is,`window.location.hostname` will not be what you probably expect it to be. From the use of `window.location.hostname` that looks more like a content script than a script for your popup.

Comment: You rolled back the changes I made to your question.  These changes included improving grammar and code formatting (inline code not formatted as code, indenting JavaScript functions, remove snippet formatting for non-runable code, removing excess whitespace, etc.). A good portion of these changes should remain in the question. What, specifically, did you object to?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version. The more complex needs you to finish :)

```
<body>
<span id="mySpan"></span>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function theCallback(theResponse) {
    var text = theResponse; // I don't know what you want... Just put the text of your response here.
    var mySpan = document.getElementById("mySpan");
    mySpan.textContent=text;
}
```

**Update**

Have a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Display_a_Popup

And the core is:

```
var text_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("text-entry.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js")
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Turtle. I've used the code you provided, but when I click on the browser add-on button, the popup appears and is empty. How is the HTML page communicating with the Javascript? I don't see any references to link the two in the response you provided.

Comment: @silverSuns the `document` is the html document.

Comment: OK, I see what it's doing now. The code you provided works, but only when I load the html page separately in a browser. I'm trying to use the html page as a popup that opens when you click on the add-on icon in the browser. When I do so, the html popup is blank.

Comment: @silverSuns, Turtle: The content you added in your "Update" is for the Firefox Add-on SDK. The APIs available to the Add-on SDK are completely incompatible with WebExtensions based add-ons. For a brief overview, see the [Introduction to Firefox add-ons in documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/introduction-to-firefox-add-ons/13574/introduction#t=201609290133319078047). for more details, see the links in that page.

Comment: @Makyen Well, I see him tag it as `firefox-webextensions` so I just answer it with firefox solutions...

Comment: @Turtle, understood. However, Firefox has four types of extensions (and other types of add-ons; for brief into, see the link above). Of the four types, WebExtensions is the least compatible with the other types, but the most compatible with other browsers. Showing a mix of types, without clearly labeling them (by type and indicating that they are mutually incompatible) increases the overall level of confusion for the people reading the answer. Given that the OP clearly is asking about WebExtensions (tag and presence of *manifest.json*), your answer would be better without the Add-on SDK info.